# Jsoup doesn't recognize a-tag

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, jsoup

I've got the following code:

```
Elements el = doc.getElementsByTag("m");


//Read the returned XML file and add the messages to the list
for(Element e : el){

    Attributes atts = e.attributes();

    String showItem = "";
    Integer showItemId = -1;

    if(e.getElementsByTag("a").size() > 0){
        showItem = e.getElementsByTag("a").get(0).text();
        showItemId = Integer.valueOf(e.getElementsByTag("a").get(0).attr("href").replace("/?p=item&i=", ""));

        Log.e("sdsuf", showItem + "//" + showItemId);

        //Remove the text contained in the a-element, as it's now stored in showItem
        e.text(e.text().replace(e.getElementsByTag("a").get(0).text(), ""));
    }else{
        Log.e("msg", "..." + e.select("a").toString());
    }
```

I know for sure, that there's an `<a href="...">` in at last one of the elements I go through. But Jsoup doesn't recognize it, no matter if I user `e.getElementsByTag()` or `e.select()`. The html inside the elements looks like this: `h&auml;lt einen Gegenstand hoch: <a href="/?p=item&i=1">Itemname</a>`

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
The XML-File looks similar to this:

```
<chat ty="f" ti="1458893782" cch="0"><m i="1121" a="Gerg" c="a" m="0" r="" d="2" t="1458893262">A message.</m><m i="61262" a="Namnodorel" c="g" m="598" r="" d="-2" t="1458893331">h&auml;lt einen Gegenstand hoch: <a href="/?p=item&i=1">Item</a></m></chat>
```

**2. Edit:**
The issue seems to occour just when I use Android Studio, in a normal java program everything works.

Comment: 1. I get the doc by a string 2. The url needs a password, so it wouldn't do anything if I'd tell you ;)

Comment: Ok and the string is what you've pasted above?

Comment: Can you please add the returned XML file content to your post?

Comment: I get the document from a string, and iterate through the "m"-elements. That works. I know that one of them contains an 'a'-element, and that's what I've pasted. This 'a'-element isn't being found by Jsoup, and that's the problem.

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce the problem if you don't give us the input? Voting to close this question.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I added it, but I don't see how it could help, as I already explained what the content of the element is that causes the problem...

Comment: did you find a solution for this I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Hala.m No, in the end I called e.html() and searched for the a-tag manually